# What is the header text in CComboBox with style CBS_DROPDOWNLIST

Tags: mfc

I have a `CComboBoxX` inherited from `CComboBox` and I do my custom `OnPaint()`. And i don't know what is the header text (text of selection), i can't get access for it. Method `OnPaint()` is overwriten, painting what I code, but when I change selection (in dropdown listbox or just using scroll button on the mouse) control displays a standard text - i'm want to disable it and paint text by myself (using `DrawText` for example).

1. My overdraw:
   [before selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehVnV.png)
2. When i change selection it draws standard text on top of mine - i'd like to disable it:
   [after selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaEan.png)

And when control will be redrawn as result i will get that on first scring as i excepted

Can someone please explain me what draws this text, how to get access for it or how to disable it. I also don’t rule out the possibility that I just don't understand and I'm doing something wrong.

I know that `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` style don't provides `CEdit` for combo. So I check it via `OnCtlColor()` message. Also I checked `CListBox` and cannot find this text too in it.

Comment: I think it's exactly the same as the currently selected item.

Comment: The [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-getcomboboxinfo) message returns details about the individual parts that comprise the combo box control.